# Why are TCP Packets going from my pc to server owned by EdgeCast Networks, Inc.?

Tags: networking, tcp, packet

I am seeing a lot of entries like this in my `Netgear DGN 1000` log for the last few weeks:

```
Wed, 2015-11-04 20:36:56 - TCP Packet - Source:192.168.0.2,63272 Destination:68.232.44.114,80 - [BLOCK]
```

From http://www.whois.com/whois/68.232.44.114 I have learned that the server is owned by `EdgeCast Networks, Inc.`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EdgeCast is a Content Distribution Network (CDN). They host servers sprinkled in major cities around the world and have a system for serving you files from the server that's nearest to you, so you always get the highest bandwidth and lowest delay.

Many of the websites you visit every day host a lot of their files, especially photos and videos, on CDNs like EdgeCast. So this is just a normal part of modern web browsing.

Other third-party CDNs include Akamai, CloudFlare, and many more.

Many of the biggest-name websites run their own CDNs, like Google's 1e100, Yahoo's yimg, YouTube's ytimg, Facebook's fbcdn, and many more.

Comment: If this is normal then, why is my router blocking this traffic? I did not configure my router to block this traffic.

Comment: Have you seen the whois data?

Comment: @Anaksunaman What kind of foul play might be involved?

Comment: @Anaksunaman, traffic sourced from a client will be using a random "high" port number. This is entirely normal for a client establishing a connection to a server/service. so this is standard The destination port is TCP/80 or the standard port for HTTP. This looks like normal traffic based on limited information.

Comment: @SusanW.Burr, if there are some sort of AV/anti-malware/privacy type of  feature built into the firewall, it may be blocking based on the specific nature of the request but I would hope they would provide better logging of such an event (although consumer devices are not known for great logging). Otherwise it should not be blocking this type of traffic as this is just like any other request for a web page.